# Etsy API target region through active listings instead of user profile

Tags: php, json, api, etsy

Playing with Etsy's API the documentation doesn't list anything under [`listings`](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listing) that I've been able to use which would allow someone to code a request like:

```
$apistateloc = 'florida'; 
$apiurl = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?api_key=' . $apikey . '&limit=' . $apilimit . '&region=' . $apistateloc;
```

The API does mention [`Associations`](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listing#section_associations) but even after looking at the associations it would appear after testing the region can be pulled from the [`userProfile`](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/userprofile):

```
$userprofile = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/' . $product->user_id . '/profile?api_key=' . $apikey));
$products[$i]["region"] = $userprofile->results[0]->region;
```

and the above works.  I thought the API Reference for [`Region`](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/region) would have allowed this:

```
$theRegion = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/private/regions?api_key=' . $apikey));
$products[$i]["region_state"] = $theRegion->results[0]->region_name;
```

but every time I run it I get a result of:

```
"region_state":"European Union"
```

is there a way in the Etsy API to target all active listings (`https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active`) with a region such as `florida`?  I am trying to make a JSON request that will be based on state, country or city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Region](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/region):

> Represents a collection of countries to which an item ships.

So with this:

```
$theRegion = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/private/regions?api_key=' . $apikey));
$products[$i]["region_state"] = $theRegion->results[0]->region_name;
```

All you are doing is returning a list of possible regions. The return body is actually this:

```
{
  "region_id": 11,
  "region_name": "European Union",
  "is_dead": false
},
 {
  "region_id": 12,
  "region_name": "Europe non-EU",
  "is_dead": false
},
 {
  "region_id": 13,
  "region_name": "South America",
  "is_dead": true
},
 {
  "region_id": 14,
  "region_name": "Africa",
  "is_dead": true
},
 {
  "region_id": 15,
  "region_name": "Central America",
  "is_dead": true
}
```

So `results[0]` is returning the first item, hence always getting `European Union`.

What you want to use instead of `Region` is the [`location` parameter](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listing#method_findalllistingactive). So your first request string will work perfectly—just replace region with location, like this:

```
$apistateloc = 'florida'; 
$apiurl = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?api_key=' . $apikey . '&limit=' . $apilimit . '&location=' . $apistateloc;
```